# What are indexed variables formally?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, formal-languages

As far as I know, some formal languages allow for indexed variables, that is for any natural number $n$ we have variables $x_1,...,x_n$. I wonder, **what are those variables formally**?
It appears to me that they behave like function symbols, since statements such as $\forall i \in \{1,...,n\}: P(x_i)$, but they can't be functions in the mathematical sense, since indexed variables are introduced way earlier. So, are there axioms that formalize this behavior of a function symbol for those, or how are they actually behaving formally? I think I have not seen any of these axioms thus far. Would it actually be possible to define indexed variables as functions in the mathematical sense?

Comment: The list of the variables is part of the specification of the language. That's all.

Comment: Having said that, in the syntax of predicate logic quantifiers are used to "deal with" objects of the domain of discourse and not with syntactical elements of formulas.

Answer (score 1):

In [predicate logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic), which is one of the tags of your question, you have several kinds of symbols: quantifiers, parentheses, logical connectives... **and an infinite set of variables.**

The use of subscripts for variables is **just a way** to denote some of the variables. When you write in your question $\forall i \in \{1,...,n\}: P(x_i)
$, the universal quantifier is not a logical sentence of first-order language. It is a way to  abbreviate the sentence $P(x_1) \wedge \dots \wedge P(x_n)$.

Comment: But isnt my sentence just an abbreviation for $\forall i (i \in \{1,...,n\} \implies P(x_i))$, which should be a logical sentence. Furthermore, I want to know for a way to write down the infinite set of variables without using "..." notation, which is what I tried to achieve. Also, could you comment on the difference between functions in the mathematical sense and indexed variables? Is it possible to define indexed variables as functions from $\{1,...,n\}$ to the relevant domain? Also, what are other ways that don't use subscripts? Thanks!

Comment: @user1578232 The problem is that $\forall i (i \in \{1,...,n\} \implies P(x_i))$ is not a sentence of first-order - FO logic. To convince yourself about that, just have a look at the way FO sentences are produced. To avoid using subscripts, you can use $a,b,c, \dots, aaa, aab, \dots$. But that is not so practical if you don't know the number of variables you want to use?

Comment: But "$\in$" is a relation symbol, so according to the link you provided and assuming $\{1,...,n\}$ has been previously defined, "$i \in \{1,...,n\}$" defines a formula as well as $P(x_i)$. Thus also this sentence gives me a formula,or am I overseeing something? As for the subscripts: yes, I guess that is one way to do it, however "..." notation isn't formal and I would like to get rid of that.

Comment: Assuming *$\{1, \dots,n\}$ has been previously defined*… is a very bad assumption. At least for FO logic. Never assume something if you have not « very good reasons to do so ». And those reasons are likely not to be good!

Comment: I am sorry but I dont see how that causes problems. If my language allows introducing abbreviations, I can just do so by the usual property of the set mentioned above, and if it doesnt I know that at least such a set exists and can then write that set in the implication. So in either case the sentence should be well defined. I am certain you are way more educated in this than I am, so am I overseeing something?

Comment: Can you list to me the sequence of FO rules you applied to get the sentence.? No more , but no less than that.

Comment: Im not entirely sure, but couldn't I write it more precisely as $\forall n \forall x_1 ... \forall x_n \forall i \forall A (P(A) \wedge i \in A \implies P(x_i))$, where $P(A):=\forall x(x \in A \iff x \leq n)$. Then again, as I am not sure how exactly the indexed variables behave **formally**, I am not sure if I am allowed to write "$\forall n \forall x_1 ... \forall x_n$". Thanks for your patience.

Comment: I forgot to mention that $n \in \mathbb{N}$ of course.

Comment: What production rules of FO sentences would you use to produce « $\forall n \forall x_1 \dots \forall x_n$ »? This is the question you have to ask yourself to answer if **this is allowed**. Bottom line, you won’t be able to find such production rules.

Comment: But what I want to express should be expressible in the language shouldn't it? What is the right way to express it in the language?

Comment: Is there a way that the $n$ that indexes the variables does not stay free? I think there might be sentences where one wants to refer to that $n$, thus needing that it is not free.